# Directory structure for large amount of files

Tags: directory, tree

I have millions of files which filenames are SHA256 hashes of the content. Due to performance reasons I do not want to store them in a single directory. My idea is to have directory structure based on the SHA256 hashes - e.g. directory `./A/A/A/A/A` would contain all files starting with AAAAA.

As an example, one hash is `AAAAAFF02F52AA70E57EA3FD67019A7A919D373915AA30393936D9CC`

Is there any way to automate creation of such directory structure (with defined subdirectories level - i.e. 5 or 10)? How can I automate the creation of this directory structure?

Comment: A sha256 digest is 64 digits, each in the range [0-9,a-z]. So no files can ever start AAAAA.  I suspect you don't really want a very deep directory tree, with each level containing at most 36 entries. I would suggest cutting the hash into 2-digit units, giving 256 directories at the first level, and 256 at each second level. That leaves an average of 256 files at the third level if you have 16 million files. Or, using only the first 3 hex digits gives you 4096 directories, each averaging 4096 files. That is a very reasonable directory size.

Comment: Using 5 levels of directory gives you one million directories at the lowest level, each one holding a few files. Using 10 levels gives you a thousand billion directories at the tenth level, less that one in ten thousand actually containing a file.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Well, one of the files is AAAAAFF02F52AA70E57EA3FD67019A7A919D373915AA30393936D9CC...

Comment: In general, it is legitimate to represent the {a..f} of hex in either uppercase or lowercase. However, I checked three sources: RFC 6234; the Wikipedia SHA-2 article; and output from my GNU `openssl dgst` command. All of then show {0..9,a..f} exclusively. So your filenames appear to have been modified for some reason. I am unclear how a hash would be a helpful name for a file, but having the notation not conform to common usage may become an issue for you.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant - in my case the files are unique samples and just for compatibility reasons I am using upper case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a framework to solve your problem, which you may need to tailor for your needs. There is a fair amount of debug and test file creation in here. The test log comes first, the script later. Queries welcome.

I assume your file count is around 16 million (actually 16 * 1024 * 1024). So I chose to have a tree with the first level having 256 directories, and each second level 256 directories (so 65,536 directories at that level), and then the files will also average 256 per directory. If you wish to pursue a 4 or 5 level scheme, the changes are minor (ask if they are not obvious).

I use `awk` to convert the sha256 names into `mv` commands, and pipe those into `bash` (about 2 lines from the end). I would recommend removing the `| bash` until you are certain the commands match your expectations. There are also clean-up lines (`rm -rf`), and some debug (`ls` and `find`) which you will wish to clean up or comment out.

The script runs in the directory where all your millions of files are, and the `"Tree"` variable is the place the overall tree will be. This needs to be on the same file system, so that mv just needs to change a directory entry for each file: if the source and target are on different file systems, mv will instead act like cp and the process will run "forever".

This is the complete test run:

```
/home/paul/SandBox/Toys/dirTree
total 8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 paul paul 1841 Dec 12 23:59 myTree
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul   32 Dec 12 23:59 myTree.log
Making test files ...
total 544
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul  17545 Dec 12 23:59 4E8A34A5010C507ADF81E3D9EEC6330A9E866D3B70857111D3A9DF5C5008BA9D
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul  90655 Dec 12 23:59 590A853F3C97C05BB55BBBDFBA988210066807C188E54B78F340F01DD48C0AF5
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul   2685 Dec 12 23:59 5B02D3A74A2E4B433D0C7DEE57446460CCE6661E3CE59918B5243B903E3358A6
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul   2051 Dec 12 23:59 6F48C65B219CA78B8C7FF03F12A8E27E1A298A541481E9B3C86645B622DCB5B1
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul  13545 Dec 12 23:59 8FED5B546352BF30E3B98E7EB8EB916DA5E2814B4227461F01173547263BB257
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul 311346 Dec 12 23:59 A8BCA57679FE42C2902D2AE70804C4C93088079B167BC99A7827295FFB34D32E
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul   2092 Dec 12 23:59 B31470EC1AF3204CF2327F12A48296F8161B51E3C30679EFA71E65AA882DCED4
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul   4602 Dec 12 23:59 C2BFA9351040ABA8F36990D0C3E3E32F70F2E94EF8D05AEDC5EE3B32270953D3
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul   7687 Dec 12 23:59 C9FA54EEF557DE7B67B66A145CCC0D65037117F0EDFF8EFCE694B56C4A6F7FEB
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul  71752 Dec 12 23:59 D3040C6348CB758498988DA5FAF086666553B27CFB7E591B5E7616C3E8373068
-rwxr-xr-x 1 paul paul   1841 Dec 12 23:59 myTree
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul paul    204 Dec 12 23:59 myTree.log

real    0m1.992s
user    0m2.196s
sys 0m0.296s
Making directory tree ...
/home/paul/SandBox/Toys/dirTree/sha256
256
65536
   262748      4 drwxr-xr-x   2 paul     paul         4096 Dec 12 23:59 ./01/B4
   262811      4 drwxr-xr-x   2 paul     paul         4096 Dec 12 23:59 ./01/F3
   262752      4 drwxr-xr-x   2 paul     paul         4096 Dec 12 23:59 ./01/B8
   262644      4 drwxr-xr-x   2 paul     paul         4096 Dec 12 23:59 ./01/4C

real    3m47.220s
user    0m42.700s
sys 0m32.900s
   135626     72 -rw-r--r--   1 paul     paul        71752 Dec 12 23:59 sha256/D3/04/D3040C6348CB758498988DA5FAF086666553B27CFB7E591B5E7616C3E8373068
   135639    308 -rw-r--r--   1 paul     paul       311346 Dec 12 23:59 sha256/A8/BC/A8BCA57679FE42C2902D2AE70804C4C93088079B167BC99A7827295FFB34D32E
   135641     20 -rw-r--r--   1 paul     paul        17545 Dec 12 23:59 sha256/4E/8A/4E8A34A5010C507ADF81E3D9EEC6330A9E866D3B70857111D3A9DF5C5008BA9D
   133634      4 -rw-r--r--   1 paul     paul         2685 Dec 12 23:59 sha256/5B/02/5B02D3A74A2E4B433D0C7DEE57446460CCE6661E3CE59918B5243B903E3358A6
   135640     92 -rw-r--r--   1 paul     paul        90655 Dec 12 23:59 sha256/59/0A/590A853F3C97C05BB55BBBDFBA988210066807C188E54B78F340F01DD48C0AF5
   135625      8 -rw-r--r--   1 paul     paul         7687 Dec 12 23:59 sha256/C9/FA/C9FA54EEF557DE7B67B66A145CCC0D65037117F0EDFF8EFCE694B56C4A6F7FEB
   135642     16 -rw-r--r--   1 paul     paul        13545 Dec 12 23:59 sha256/8F/ED/8FED5B546352BF30E3B98E7EB8EB916DA5E2814B4227461F01173547263BB257
   135624      4 -rw-r--r--   1 paul     paul         2051 Dec 12 23:59 sha256/6F/48/6F48C65B219CA78B8C7FF03F12A8E27E1A298A541481E9B3C86645B622DCB5B1
   135628      4 -rw-r--r--   1 paul     paul         2092 Dec 12 23:59 sha256/B3/14/B31470EC1AF3204CF2327F12A48296F8161B51E3C30679EFA71E65AA882DCED4
   135630      8 -rw-r--r--   1 paul     paul         4602 Dec 12 23:59 sha256/C2/BF/C2BFA9351040ABA8F36990D0C3E3E32F70F2E94EF8D05AEDC5EE3B32270953D3

real    0m2.118s
user    0m0.528s
sys 0m1.520s
```

This is the script:

```
#! /bin/bash

Tree="sha256"

#.. Fake some test files from man pages, renamed with their own sha256.

mkFile () {

    local Fn
    local Awk='{ printf ("%s\n", toupper ($(NF))); }'

    man -s 1 "${1}" > Man
    Fn=$( openssl dgst -sha256 Man | awk "${Awk}" )
    mv Man "${Fn}"
}

#.. Make a directory tree for the first 4 hex characters of any name,
#.. such that files 7BC12A13... go into ./7B/C1.

mkDirs () {

    local a b c d
    for a in {0..9} {A..F}; do
        for b in {0..9} {A..F}; do
            for c in {0..9} {A..F}; do
                for d in {0..9} {A..F}; do
                    mkdir -p ./${a}${b}/${c}${d}
                done
            done
        done
    done
}

#.. Move all files in the current directory that have sha256-type names
#.. into their appropriate directory.

mvFiles () {

    local Awk='
BEGIN {
    FS = "/";
    cmd = "mv -t \047%s/%s/%s\047 \047%s\047\n";
}
length ($NF) == 64 && $NF ~ /^[[:xdigit:]]*$/ {
    printf (cmd, Tree, substr ($NF, 1, 2), substr ($NF, 3, 2), $NF);
}
'
    awk -v Tree="${Tree}" -f <( printf '%s' "${Awk}" ) -
}

#.. Tests.

    #.. Nothing up my sleeves.
    pwd
    ls -l

    #.. Make some test files.
    [ x ] && time (
        echo "Making test files ..."
        for tx in cut cat ls find wc dd bash awk vi dc; do
            mkFile "${tx}"
        done
        ls -l
    )

    #.. Make a directory tree.
    [ x ] && time (
        echo "Making directory tree ..."
        rm -rf ${Tree}
        mkdir -p ${Tree}
        cd ${Tree} || exit

        pwd
        mkDirs
        ls -d * | wc -l
        ls -d */* | wc -l
        find . -ls | tail -n +1299 | head -n 4
    )

    #.. Move all the local sha256 files into the tree.
    [ x ] && time (
        find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | mvFiles "${Tree}" | bash
        find "${Tree}" -type f -ls
    )
```

Comment: @Petr Are we going anywhere with this? Seems to me the performance hit now is in running 16 million `mv` processes. The `mv -t` options allows one target directory and many source files, so reworking mvFiles to group files by target might get a x200 performance gain. Comment if you feel the need.